# CFT OPE for operators with spin

Tags: operators, quantum-spin, conformal-field-theory

I am wondering whether the OPE for two operators, where at least one of them have spin, is known. If so, how it differs from the OPE for two operators without spin?

I am quite certain this OPE is known since we are able to reduce a n-point correlator down to two-points using the OPE (with constants from the three-point).

Comment: In 2d the question for operators with is essentially the same as for scalars. In 3d and higher the question for operators with spins can be arbitrarily complicated, depending on the spin. However, there are many efficient techniques for computing it, for example by relating it to scalar OPE. Is there something particular that you want to know?

Comment: In my case I consider a d = 4 - \epsilon dimensional CFT, and I want to reduce a 3-point correlator for fields with different spin down to a 2-point correlator. I have no constraints on what kinds of spin the fields in the  3-point correlator have.  Basically what I need is the OPE for 2 fields with different spin.  I guess the 3d case would be fine as well, since I can always let \epsilon go to one.

Comment: This is a bit weird thing to do because the 3 pt functions are fixed by symmetry anyway. Here are some references on spinning correlation functions [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3554), [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08987), [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7351). Here are some papers methods of which allow you to reduce spinning OPE to scalar OPE: [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6321), [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03750.pdf), [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07813).

Comment: Most of the time people think about conformal blocks and not OPE itself. For conformal blocks many other methods are available. Some of them may also be adapted to OPE, but the ones from the references I gave can be directly applied to OPE. Also, this list of references is of course not complete.

Comment: Thanks for the useful references. I will be sure to study them. And yes, reducing a three-point to a two-point function is a very unusual thing to do. The reason I suggested it was because I assumed the three-point function for fields with spin is not known. 

I see that in the references you sent me they often addresses the problem of finding correlators with tensors that have spin. My problem is slightly simpler than that since I only have scalars with spin or only have vectors with spin.

Comment: I am completely confused, what is a "scalar with spin"? By definition, spin of a scalar is 0.

Comment: Oh wait, what am I saying? Yeah I can see your confusion since scalars do not carry spin.  Sorry about that. What I meant was that I have vectors (1 Lorentz index) on my fields. Though that is already covered in the articles you sent me.